# CSS background-position will not center

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble centering my background. Whether I change the BG into small size to make it center it won't.

Her is my CSS:

```
#container {    
    background-image: url(Photos/BG.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    height: 1813px;
    width: 1024px;
}
```

It doesn't center the background - it keeps going to the top left of the monitor even though using a smaller size photo. Thank you all!

Comment: Your code works as you would expect. There's probably a different CSS rule interfering.

Comment: The issue is **either** your CSS is not loading, **or** you have a conflict with other markup / styles.  You can see in [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cale_b/r3fpg8nn/) that your css works just fine.

Comment: at first i put a single 'center' still doesnt work. but i now have a solution by putting margin: auto; it will center automatically in any resolution. thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

To centralise the background image you don't need to specify center center twice. It should be as follows:

```
 #container {    
    background-image: url(Photos/BG.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    height: 1813px;
}
```

Comment: This isn't really an **answer to the issue**, this is an *optional method* to specify center / center (either `center center` OR `center` are valid options)

Comment: at first i put a single 'center' still doesnt work. but i now have a solution by putting margin: auto; it will center automatically in any resolution. thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as aspected, if you remove the width you will see exactly the image centered in the background...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        #container {    
    background-image: url('http://supermario3dworld.nintendo.com/_ui/img/views/power-ups/char-dobble-mario.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center; /* you dont need to specify the value two times */
    height: 1813px;

            background-color: aquamarine;
}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why remove the width? That shouldn't be required.

Comment: only to see the background is centered and it will be centered for every width

Comment: thank you for the reply sir. appreciate it. but if i remove the width the BG photo will expand and or it will stretch thus making the BG a bit odd. but i have found a solution by putting margin as auto. thank you so much. im learning now.

Answer (score -1):

```
background-image: url(path-to-file/img.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
```

should work, one other thing you could do is make a div and put the img in it, then use -1 z-index and just center the div.

You could also try adding

```
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

because the container might not be the full viewport size.

Comment: thank you for your time sir. i didnt try putting z-index. my solution was putting the margin as auto.